# Check actual URL used for request in Mule HTTP Connector

Tags: mule

I'm working on a flow that includes an `<http:request>` element, but I keep getting unexpected 404 responses.  Is there a way for me to check the actual URL that is being requested?

I can't see any way to do this within Mule.  I also tried using Fiddler as a proxy but can't get any sessions to show up in Fiddler for the requests starting from Mule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a proxy like CharlesProxy: http://www.charlesproxy.com/ or something but you can also just use log4j. If you try adding this to your log4j2 configuration:

```
    <AsyncLogger name="org.glassfish.grizzly" level="DEBUG" />
    <AsyncLogger name="org.asynchttpclient" level="DEBUG" />
    <AsyncLogger name="com.ning.http" level="DEBUG" />
```

For a HTTP request using the http:request to http://google.com, it logs the following:

DEBUG 2015-07-14 13:18:17,416 [[test].test.worker.01] com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyConnectionsPool: [poll] No existing queue for uri [http://google.com:80].
DEBUG 2015-07-14 13:18:17,449 [[test].http.requester.httprequest(1) SelectorRunner] com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider: REQUEST: HttpRequestPacket (
   method=GET
   url=/
   query=null
   protocol=HTTP/1.1
   content-length=-1
   headers=[
      Host=google.com:80
      Connection=keep-alive
      Accept=*/*
      User-Agent=NING/1.0]
)

Comment: Hm... I added these lines to my log4j2.xml file (after copying the default configuration) but I'm not seeing the debugs in my console as you are.  I checked that my log configuration is working by changing all the other log levels to DEBUG and confirming that massive amounts of log are generated.

Comment: I missed one sorry. Updated my answer - Added com.ning.http.

Comment: thanks for the help earlier.  Looks like the URLs are correct, but I'm still getting unexpected 404s -- would you mind taking a look at my [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417797/unexpected-404-using-mule-3-6-http-connector)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on MAC, you could try Wireshark. Fiddler does not indeed capture the HTTP request from Mule, from my experience as well.