# Unexpected 404 using Mule 3.6 HTTP Connector

Tags: mule

I'm getting unexpected 404 errors using the new HTTP connector and can't figure out why.

This curl makes the same call I'm trying to make, and works as expected:

```bash
curl -H "X-AuntBertha-Signature: AUTH_SIG" \
    https://searchbertha-hrd.appspot.com/_ah/api/search/v1/programs/4818166?api_key=MY_API_KEY \
    > resources_dump.json
```

However, this flow does NOT working.  Vendor told me that they don't even see the request show up in their logs, so something is funky.

```xml
<http:request-config name="AuntBertha_Production"  host="searchbertha-hrd.appspot.com" basePath="/_ah/api/search/v1/" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" port="443" protocol="HTTPS" />
<!-- clipped... -->

<flow name="FetchResource">
    <!-- clipped... -->

    <http:request config-ref="AuntBertha_Production" path="/programs/4818166" method="GET" doc:name="Fetch from AB">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="api_key" value="MY_API_KEY"/>
            <http:header headerName="X-AuntBertha-Signature" value="AUTH_SIG"/>
        </http:request-builder>
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="200,404,500"/>
    </http:request>
```

And here are the logs I'm getting in my console (after help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406437/378482)):

```
DEBUG 2015-07-14 16:19:55,202 [[resource_bulk_upload].HTTP_Default_Listener.worker.01] com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyConnectionsPool: [poll] Found pooled connection [TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={/192.168.0.2:49878}, peerSocketAddress={searchbertha-hrd.appspot.com/209.85.147.141:443}}] for uri [https://searchbertha-hrd.appspot.com:443].
DEBUG 2015-07-14 16:19:55,203 [[resource_bulk_upload].HTTP_Default_Listener.worker.01] com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider: REQUEST: HttpRequestPacket (
   method=GET
   url=/_ah/api/search/v1/programs/4818166
   query=api_key=MY_API_KEY
   protocol=HTTP/1.1
   content-length=-1
   headers=[
      Host=searchbertha-hrd.appspot.com:443
      X-AuntBertha-Signature=AUTH_SIG
      Connection=keep-alive
      Accept=*/*
      User-Agent=NING/1.0]
)
DEBUG 2015-07-14 16:19:55,262 [[resource_bulk_upload].http.requester.AuntBertha_Production(3) SelectorRunner] com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider: RESPONSE: HttpResponsePacket (
  status=404
  reason=Not Found
  protocol=HTTP/1.1
  content-length=-1
  committed=false
  headers=[
      cache-control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
      pragma=no-cache
      expires=Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
      date=Tue, 14 Jul 2015 21:19:49 GMT
      vary=X-Origin
      content-type=text/html; charset=UTF-8
      x-content-type-options=nosniff
      x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN
      x-xss-protection=1; mode=block
      server=GSE
      alternate-protocol=443:quic,p=1
      accept-ranges=none
      transfer-encoding=chunked]
)
```

If I change the request to ping e.g. google.com instead, it works as expected.  What am I missing here?  What's the mismatch between my working `curl` and broken `<flow>`?

Comment: I've seen services rejecting requests with `404` for User-Agents they deemed to be bots. Here, Mule's user agent is `NING/1.0`: could you try `curl` with `-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"` just to see if you can reproduce the issue from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

404 not found means it did connect somewhere and got a 404 response back.

So your call is actually successful from a network perspective.

So the code basically works. It could be either like David suggested a Header issue, like user-agent is wrong or the IP/domain calling is wrong, or the Mule node executing the request has some custom proxy configuration or similar. But your statement of "code does not work", I am not sure, the code actually works, it seems the configuration is what does not work.

Comment: Right - the question is -- to where did it connect, and why did it get a 404 response?   It does *not* seem to be connecting to `https://searchbertha-hrd.appspot.com/_ah/api/search/v1/programs/4818166?api_key=MY_API_KEY` -- which is what I would expect based on the configuration.  But I can't figure out what it *is* connecting to or how to fix it.